# Using thread for parallel processing in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need few of the functions in my program to run simultaneously. These processes returns records. But, the output of one is the input to the other. In such a case, if at a point of time function A takes some time to output some record to the function B, I need to the function B to wait till function A provides some records as input for this process. Can I achieve this simply by using the thread functionalities such as wait, join, etc.. Or Is there any other ways to achieve the same functionality.

Edited:
As per the below mentioned suggestions, If I use the producer-consumer algorithm with BlockingQueue,ExecutorService, Future and CountDownLatch, Can I achieve every functionalities I requested?

Comment: Check out the classes in package `java.util.concurrent`

Comment: If you have a very simple task you could just have a `volatile` variable that will act as a flag. If you have more complex functionality you will need to  have a `concurrent` variable for the data used by both threads. There are plenty implementations for concurrency in Java libraries so just pick something from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above you can use blocking queue with producer consumer

OR

You can use countdown latch of the java concurrency to solve your problem.

**How CountDownLatch works?**

CountDownLatch.java class defines one constructor inside:

//Constructs a CountDownLatch initialized with the given count.

```
public void CountDownLatch(int count) {...}
```

This count is essentially the number of threads, for which latch should wait. This value can be set only once, and CountDownLatch provides no other mechanism to reset this count.

The first interaction with CountDownLatch is with main thread which is goind to wait for other threads. This main thread must call, **CountDownLatch.await()** method immediately after starting other threads. The execution will stop on await() method till the time, other threads complete their execution.

Other N threads must have reference of latch object, because they will need to notify the CountDownLatch object that they have completed their task. This notification is done by method : **CountDownLatch.countDown()**; Each invocation of method decreases the initial count set in constructor, by 1. So, when all N threads have call this method, count reaches to zero, and main thread is allowed to resume its execution past await() method.

Below is a simple example. After the Decrementer has called countDown() 3 times on the

```
CountDownLatch, the waiting Waiter is released from the await() call.
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

Waiter      waiter      = new Waiter(latch);
Decrementer decrementer = new Decrementer(latch);

new Thread(waiter)     .start();
new Thread(decrementer).start();

Thread.sleep(4000);

public class Waiter implements Runnable{

    CountDownLatch latch = null;

    public Waiter(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Waiter Released");
    }
}

public class Decrementer implements Runnable {

    CountDownLatch latch = null;

    public Decrementer(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.latch.countDown();

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.latch.countDown();

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.latch.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In your case you can use callable to create thread instead of runnable as you need to get the retrun value from one thread and have to pass that value to second thread.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases you do not need to use `wait` etc. All you need to do is choose a good safe structure to use to communicate between your threads,

In this specific case I would suggest one of the concurrent queuue implementations, perhaps a `BlockingQueue` such as [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html).

Comment: +1. yes.. using `BlockingQueue` is perhaps the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Java's Fork and Join looks suitable for the usecase specified in your Question.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) classes and producer/consumer patterns.

The first thread is getting the work unit from an input blocking queue and putting its output to an output blocking queue (with size restrictions).
The second thread is doing the using this output queue as an input.
With this method you can also easialy adjust the number of threads.

Ensure the the work load per work unit is not to small.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to producer-consumer problem. You can use Java's [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

The process A will enqueue its results and the process B will wait until A's output is ready in the queue. When output of A is available, then B can read and consume it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the consumer-producer-problem. As suggested by others you can use a `BlockingQueue`. Here is an example for how to use it:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final ExecutorService producer = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final ExecutorService consumer = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final BlockingQueue<Integer> workpieces = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    producer.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Random rand = new Random();

            for (;;) {
                try {
                    workpieces.put(rand.nextInt());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    });

    consumer.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (;;) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Got " + workpieces.take());
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```

It generates a random number every second in the producer-thread which is printed by the consumer-thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BlockingQueue between producer and consumer threads. The producer will keep on adding results to queue if it is not full, concurrently the consumer thread can process pending messages from queue.